# Remove Microsoft Edge and Store taskbar shortcuts for all new users - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, shortcuts

I already know that pinned shortcuts can be found in `%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar`, but the 2 shortcuts I mentioned in my title are not in there (they're not in the Default user either). I'm trying to make it so that those 2 shortcuts are not created when a new user logs in.

I also thought of deleting them after the user logs in (such as with a logon script on our Windows domain), but I can't do that if I don't know where they are stored. Any ideas?

Comment: [Customize the Default User Profile by Using CopyProfile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898521(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: OK, thanks. This looks like quite the steep learning curve though (and I have to reinstall Windows from what I understand). I'll give it a shot, since this would be useful for far more than just removing some shortcuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are saved under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband`.

You can replace the whole key with a first logon script.

Comment: This is indeed the correct location for those shortcuts. Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you mean by "replace the whole key"? There are a few key-value pairs, and they are binary formatted. Not that easy to modify it seems. Could you give a hint on how to approach that.

Answer (score 0):

Save code in reg file and import in registry of default user:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce]
"RemoveEdge&StoreFromTaskbar"="powershell -Command \"Remove-Item \"HKCU:\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\Taskband\" -Recurse -Force; Stop-Process -Processname Explorer -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -force\""
```